# Replaced all A/C components - Outlet temperature still subpar

Tags: ford, temperature, expedition, navigator

I purchased a 2006 Lincoln Navigator (5.4 Ford, with a separate front and rear A/C system) a couple of years ago and it seemed to be maintained very well, but the A/C was performing poorly in hot weather, especially at idle or in stop and go traffic. With the climate control modules on the coldest setting, with the front and rear fans on the highest setting, and with the front climate control module on recirc mode (the rear A/C can only do recirc)...... the outlet temperature wouldn't get below around 48 degrees Fahrenheit, and it would only muster that low of a temperature if I was barreling down the highway with the A/C on full blast for a while. Thinking the charge was low, I added refrigerant 2 summers ago and blew the front seal on the compressor. I took it upon myself to learn more about automotive A/C systems, and installed a brand new compressor, drier/accumulator, condenser, both evaporators, both expansion valves, schrader valves on the high/low ports new pressure switches, all new O-rings, new blend door actuators for the front and rear, new evaporator temperature sensor, etc. The only thing that wasn't replaced on the system was the climate control module in the dash (works just fine) and the hard lines that run to and from the rear evaporator under the car. Those lines were flushed properly with A/C flush solvent, and dried out with dry air.

The compressor was completely drained of PAG oil before installation, and I added 14 oz of PAG 46 oil, and used a Snap On A/C machine to fill the system with exactly 54 oz of Dupont R134A. This is exactly what the system calls for. Everything seemed to be operating fine, there seemed to be no blockages on the lines, compressor was cycling on and off at a normal frequency, but while idling the truck's outlet temperature wouldn't get below 60-some degrees on an 86 degree day. I ran it down the highway for a bit, and was able to get my usual 47-48 degree outlet temperature, but still couldn't get below that.

We tried adding a little more refrigerant, and a little less, but neither seemed to help. Last summer, we evacuated the system and then re-charged it with the same 54 oz, and replaced the amount of PAG oil that was recovered, but no improvements. I gave up on this A/C system and suffered slow-moving, 45 minute commutes home in 95+ degree weather, with an outlet temperature of around 65 degrees, until I could finally hit highway speeds.

I know that some will say that 65 degree outlet temp on a 95 degree day is normal, or that 48 degrees while barreling down the highway on an 84 degree day is pretty satisfactory-- but that's absolutely not the case. Every other vehicle I've owned, of about 14 vehicles, including an older '97 Expedition, has always produced outlet temps between 38 and 42 degrees, and they will do it while idling, let alone at highway speeds. And 65+ degree outlet temperature on a 95+ degree day, especially when the sun is beating down on the truck (I have tinted windows all the way around, which combats the sun some)... it just doesn't cool the cabin down worth a darn. Even in 55 degrees weather, I can't see better than around 48 degrees outlet temperature.

This truck only idles at around 550 RPM from the factory, and increasing the throttle to around 1,000 RPM while in park or neutral seemed to improved the outlet temps at idle by just a couple degrees, so I don't think it's all in the idle. But today, our first day in the 90's this year (91 degrees to be exact), I noticed that the A/C compressor clutch never cycled off (I use a Bluetooth OBD-II adapter and the FORscan app... and I've watched the PID for the A/C clutch cycle on and off with it plenty of times in the past and recently) while I was in bumper-to-bumper traffic and the outlet temps for 55-60 degrees, nor when I was doing around 55 MPH for around 10 minutes and the outlet temperature finally slowly dropped to around 48 degrees. I'd like to understand why the compressor did not cycle off in today's hotter weather, especially when I finally got the cabin cooled down a bit.

I've seen the F-150 guys do a mod where you add a resistor between the wires on the evaporator temperature sensor, which tricks the climate control module into thinking that the evaporator temperature is warmer than it actually is, therefor allowing the compressor clutch to remain engaged longer and help produce better cooling. I've tried that with several resistors, and no improvements. Plus with the compressor clutch only staying engaged the entire drive home today, clearly running the compressor longer (or 100% of the time) does not help. I've added two 12" cooling fans (puller fans) the back of the condenser, and they don't help with the outlet temperatures. I've reached my hand into the front and rear plenum and touched both evaporators, and they are never that cold at idle.

The blend doors are all working properly. The door that blocks off the outside air to the front plenum is sealing off perfectly, the blend doors responsible for mixing the evaporator and heater core air are sealing properly and the new actuators are working properly.... everything is working exactly as it should. I've even tried clamping off coolant flow to the heater cores and no improvements at idle nor at highway speeds... so hot air is absolutely not entering the front nor rear plenum.

What gives???? I've spent so much money in trying to get this system to perform better, but nothing has improved. I'm desperate at this point, and everyone I know that I've talked to about this has nothing to suggest after everything I've done and tried. Any solid help would be extremely appreciated!!

Thanks,
Andrew

P.S. Here are some videos from last summer, of some manifold gauges I hooked up to car. It covers the static pressures, as well as the low side and high side pressures while the system is running:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWUIvkkh26M

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnKoOQyNXxQ

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmmeATamEGU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enXrsuoLcyI

The videos would have to be played in the above order to make sense. Warning: The videos are as long as my post lol.

EDIT 5/4/18: I failed to mention that I also have a brand new fan and fan clutch assembly that I installed last year, which did not improve anything unfortunately.

Comment: Probably the most important data needed for proper ac diagnostics is the static, low, and high side pressures. I suggest getting those numbers and then update your question.

Comment: Thank you Milison, I just added some videos of the gauge pressures from last year :)

Comment: is the engine fan working?

Comment: You clearly have a condenser heat rejection issue, probably due to too small of a condenser or not enough airflow. Strangely enough the high pressure switch won't get tripped. When you're stationary, you have the engine on and the AC on, do this. Keep spraying water on the condenser, and check if three things happen: 1)the compressor clutch eventually disengages 2)the discharge (high) pressure decreases 3)the vent temperature lowers.

Comment: The fact that you blew the seal so easily when you added the refrigerant might be a sign that the system was working with abnormal discharge pressures and the seal was, therefore, already worn to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the responses gentlemen. Jason, I failed to mention that originally, but I just added to the post that I installed a new fan and clutch assembly last year, even though the original seemed to be working properly.

Hi Al, I can give that a try, but just so I understand, what is the purpose of that test? To cool the condenser? This is a new Motorcraft condenser, so I feel like if size was an issue that would be a problem on all Expeditions and Navigators. It's actually a pretty sizeable condenser.

Comment: I've also added those two 12" puller fans behind it, and they suck some good air. I've also driven the the car with the A/C on it 50 degree weather, which surely keeps the condenser cool at highway speeds, and still can only manage to get around 48 degrees outlet temperature. Just puzzling that no circumstance seems to allow this thing to cool better. You would think heat is getting mixed it, but I've ruled that out by clamping off the coolant flow to and from the heater cores.

Comment: This is puzzling indeed. But if all your fans are, for any reason, pulling hot air from the bay through the condenser, the condenser warms up, while it should do the exact opposite. So the water spray on the condenser fins thing is meant to test if it's an airflow issue. Do the test in 90 F and more weather and if it fails, the only other thing i can think about is an undersized compressor (consider that you have rear ac too and also keep in mind that if the rear evaporator has a TXV but no liquid line solenoid valve, something is flowing through it even when the rear blower is off).

Comment: By spraying water on the condenser fins, yes, you're cooling it. You're forcing it to do its own work because the cool water takes away the heat required to turn into vapor. How can hot air from the bay be pulled through the condenser? For example, if it's mounted right in front of the radiator and there's a sizable gap (more than 1 inch) between it and the condenser, and the gap isn't sealed with foam, well, the fans pull a lot of air from the side, hence from the engine bay, and not through the condenser fins. And that's why you only get coldish air when you're rolling on the highway.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the explanation Al. I can certainly said that while idling, with or without the auxiliary electric fans that I installed turned on, the condenser is warm to the touch, but definitely not hot. Turning the electric fans on brings the temperature of the condenser down some, but not enough to improve the outlet temperatures. 

The new condenser still has the rubber seals from the old condenser installed, helping seal off the engine bay heat. The compressor is also from Motorcraft (all replacement A/C parts have been original Motorcraft) so not sure why it would be too small...

Comment: ...if this is everything the car had from the factory, part number for part number.

Even though the condenser does not seem to get heat-soaked from the engine by at idle, I still think it's worth me trying what you said, so I'll try to get all of that done the next ~90 degree day we have and report with the results. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Are there any electric condenser fans?

Comment: Just to throw this out there, and I'm not sure how strong your air flow is, but have you ever changed or even checked your cabin filter? Could be pretty dirty and clogged. Good luck.

Comment: @Mustangguy809 If that were the problem the little airflow that managed to reach the vents would've been colder, and the compressor would cycle even more due to the LPCO switch tripping due to the freezing evaporator. But he clearly said that on a hot day, the compressor never cycled. Cabin filter affects cabin temperature, not vent one.

Comment: Hi Moab, from the factory the truck just uses a fan/clutch assembly driven by the water pump pulley. I've added two slim 12" puller fans behind the condenser to help draw outside air thru the condenser, but it has not improved anything.

Unfortunately this truck has no cabin air filter placement, but as Al mentioned, that wouldn't affect outlet temperature during recirc mode. Air flow is definitely plenty though, and when I disassembled the plenum last summer to replace the heater core and evaporator it was very clean. :)

Comment: @Andrew Wrong. If there's a cabin filter, it lies between the evaporator and the recirc door. So, even if recirculation is on, the air still passes through that filter. That is meant to simplify the heater unit/front box. In recirc mode, the airflow somewhat increases only because the air has to travel less distance. More filter resistance means less heat exchange and colder evaporator so the outlet temperature actually goes down with a dirty cabin filter (until the LPCO/frost sensor triggers or the compressor stroke decreases, that is).

Comment: Hi Al, I guess it depends on the vehicle. I haven't purchased a new vehicle in 5 or 6 years, but everything I've owned that has been equipped with a cabin air filter has been on the engine bay side of the firewall, only filtering outside air. When the recirc door is closed off from outside air, the filter is sealed off. Maybe that's not applicable to other and/or newer vehicles, from what you're saying.

Comment: So I probably won't have a chance to hook up the gauges over the next few weeks with how busy I'll be with some other things, but I noticed something today. It was about 85 degrees out, the engine was completely cooled down since the night before, and I fired it up and turned the A/C on to try to starting cooling down the cabin before I drove off. Within 30 seconds of starting the car up and turning on the A/C I was under the hood and noticed the condenser was EXTREMELY. So was the high pressure line coming from it. Like, burn your skin type of hot....

Comment: I checked again after 10 mins or so went by, and the condenser and high pressure line were significantly cooler. This seems to correlate with the videos I linked in my original post, from last year, when I first started the car for the morning, turned the A/C on, and the high side pressure shot wayyyyyyyyy up. The high side spiking like this seems to indicate a clog or blockage somewhere.... but I can't see how that's possible. All lines that weren't replaced (pretty much only the lines that run to the rear evaporator) were flushed and had no restrictions when blowing 90 PSI thru them...

Comment: Everything else is line-wise is brand new, and the condenser, accumulator/drier, both evaporators, both TXVs, the compressor.... ALL of that is new. I had even blown dry air thru the condensor before installing it just to make sure it was good. What gives???? Could the TXVs need adjustment?????

Also, why would the "blockage" only appear every time the car has sat and cooled completely (assuming that's what's happening), and go away after the system has ran for several minutes???....

Comment: When the physical temperature of the condenser returns to normal, the the "blockage" must have been freed, but the outlet temperature never gets below around 47 degrees (I did see 44 degrees yesterday, after driving around with the A/C full blast for 30 minutes in 80-degree weather). I just truly don't understand what's going wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried doing what i told you yet? High discharge temperature correlates to high discharge pressure and that means you're running a very high head pressure. Normal with such a large car (as to require rear AC) as soon as you turn AC on with an hot cabin (you're transfering all that heat to the condenser). Again, it sounds like an airflow or undersized condenser issue to me. You've flushed and replaced everything you could so a blockage, even a strange one that "frees" up after some time running the system, or a TXV with a way wrong superheat setting, should be out of the question.

Comment: Try repeating it in cool weather (or in the night time) beginning from a cold cabin and see if you can replicate that hot condenser thing. And if you truly had a blockage it would immediately trip the high pressure switch, disengaging the clutch (provided you have one; if you have one, please tell me where it is located along the high pressure side).

Comment: Thanks for the continued help Al. No Sir, I have yet to do that-- I'm going to have to wait for a day I can borrow the gauge set from my buddy, on a day that the weather is right and I'm not busy with too many things. In the meantime, I can surely see if the condenser still gets really hot after first start-up on a cooler day and let you know. My  high side pressure switch is located on the hard (aluminum) line that bolts to the condenser, probably just 7" or so from the condenser.

Comment: So back to the air flow or undersized condenser issue, just so I can wrap my head around this, what would allow that to be an issue if everything is OEM and nothing has changed in terms of the path of flow in front of nor behind the condenser, nor the sides of the condenser? Radiator sitting behind the condenser has clear passages thru the fins, the fan shroud is installed properly, the fan and clutch are new, etc?  My low 500 RPM idle in gear probably doesn't help when I'm in stop and go traffic, but that of course has no impact while barreling down the highway. Just trying to understand :)

Comment: Well, a bad AC system design can't be ruled out. The problem is, you need to know why it's bad. For this you have to help the condenser do its job by keeping a mist of water over it with the A/C system turned on and see what happens. For the airflow issue, you have to be 100% sure that all the air is being pulled from the outside and is going through the condenser fins. If you were to follow the TXV superheat problem then what you should do is reduce the superheat (there's a spindle on the valve for superheat), so that more liquid is flowing through the evaporator at all times.

Comment: But i don't recommend you doing it, because, since it's a dual evaporator system, you could potentially throw the system out of balance. Another question about the HP switch: is it located on the tubing between the compressor and the condenser, or the one between the condenser and the tee leading to the evaporators? If you want to look for any blockages, you have to look right before the HP switch, because it seems your clutch isn't cycling.

Comment: So, anything new about your air con?

Comment: Hi Al thanks for following up! Unfortunately I just haven't had the time lately. The compressor has been cycling on and off as normal since that 90-degree day when I started this thread 4 weeks ago. We also haven't had any 90+ degree days since then, but I do need to see if that condenser is at least hot to the touch every time I turn on the A/C for the first time of the day... I suppose I keep forgetting to do that. Going to see if I can remember to do that this weekend, at the very least :) The HP switch is between the condenser and the split to both evaporators by the way.

Comment: I do know that when I have fired up the electric fans I installed, they will suck a flat sheet of paper right against the front of the condensor with a bit of strength, so the condenser does seem to be flowing just fine. While changing my upper control arms a couple weeks ago, I did manage to find a plastic shipping cap used for an A/C line set on this car, that had fallen to an area that couldn't easily be reached. It looked pretty old, so seems like someone else had been fiddling with replacing stuff too at some point in the past, perhaps trying to fix the same problem I've been after?? Lol.